# color picker that returns named colors

Tags: css, color

I'm looking for a color picker that will enable me to have CSS color names of any pixel of an image that I point at. I mean the program has to somehow approximate the pixel data to convert the actual color to its closest named color (as defined by CSS 3, for example). Or I'll be happy even with the software that would allow me to create such mappings on my own. The point is that I need to pick a pixel and then to have its color information "coarsened" so as to be classified as belonging to a more general class (say, greens, reds, etc., and preferably, CSS 3 named colors).

I would be happy with either a Windows 10 or a web-based solution. As to the price, it depends on the details but paid solutions are fine with me. Anyway, I'm ready to consider all available options.
Kind regards, Svetlana